# C# Generic Method from Base Class

Tags: c#, generics, methods, abstract, radix

I have the following scenario:

```
public abstract class AAA<T> where T : BBB<T>
{
}

public abstract class BBB<T> : AAA<T> where T : BBB<T>
{
    public void SomeMethod() { }
}

public class CCC : BBB<CCC>
{
}
```

And they are in turn used with the following.

```
public class YYY
{
    public void Bar(BBB bbb, int value)
    {
        bbb.SomeMethod();
    }
}

public class ZZZ : YYY
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        CCC instance = new CCC();
        Bar(instance, 0);
    }
}
```

How do I structure the declaration of `YYY.Bar()` for parameter `bbb` so that it can accept an argument of type `CCC`?  Class `ZZZ` knows about type `CCC`, but class `YYY` only has knowledge of `AAA` and `BBB`.  This is common practice in other languages, e.g. Java, but I can't seem to make it work in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your method `Bar` generic:

```cs
public class YYY
{
    public void Bar<T>(BBB<T> bbb, int value) where T : BBB<T>
    {
        bbb.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

Another option is to make `YYY` generic itself, not sure if it is suitable in your scenario though:

```cs
public class YYY<T> where T : BBB<T>
{
    public void Bar(BBB<T> bbb, int value)
    {
        bbb.SomeMethod();
    }
}

public class ZZZ : YYY<CCC>
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        CCC instance = new CCC();
        Bar(instance, 0);
    }
}
```